# Trouble using ./<file> in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

So I downloaded a python program and I was told to run the program by using `./<filename> -h`. However, when I do so, I get the following error:

```
bash: ./<filename>: Permission denied
```

So I figured I just needed to put sudo in front of the command. Therefore I change it to `sudo ./<filename> -h` and then I get:

```
sudo: ./<filename>: Command not found
```

Can somebody help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
chmod +x filename
```

It will grant execution permissions for this file.